# Get Radio Type, Channel and Encryption from Managed Wifi API c#

Tags: c#, wlanapi

can someone please tell me how I can extract **Radio Type**, **Channel** and **Encryption** information through **Managed Wifi API** in C#? I am able to see all the above information in my command prompt through "netsh wlan show interfaces" command (when I am connected to Wifi), however I am not looking to use this command and get the info in C#.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After doing lot of googling and R&D, I have found some solution of my problem. I have drilled down "**WlanInterface**" class under "**WlanClient**" class through which I was able to extract "Channel" and "Encryption" values. "Encryption" was little tricky, the code snippet is as follows:

```
 Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks =    wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
                    Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network = networks.Where(x => x.flags.HasFlag(Wlan.WlanAvailableNetworkFlags.Connected)).FirstOrDefault(); 
                    muObject.Encryption = network.dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm.ToString();
```

I have extracted "Radio Type" from netsh wlan query until I find the perfect solution... :-)